# Bootstrap Card navigates to different route on click in angular 8

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, accordion

I am simply trying to use bootstrap 4 card in an accordion in my angular application. The html is below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="accordion">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
    Collapsible Group Item #2
  </a>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
      Collapsible Group Item #3
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is when I click on any of the header links, it navigates me to that route

```
http://localhost:4200/#collapseOne
```

instead of showing/hiding the card body. Anybody came across such issue?

Comment: its working fine . used CDN?

Comment: @nikhilsugandh no i have a npm package install for bootstrap

Comment: did you import it??

Comment: yes all other bootstrap controls are working fine. This is something related to routing I guess

Comment: but where inyour code there is route?? put angular code

Comment: how can you open a accordion like that:`http://localhost:4200/#collapseOne`

Comment: I haven't added any angular logic to this page. I am assuming href is using routing by default which shouldnt happen coz its appending the url with href value

Comment: I am not creating this url http://localhost:4200/#collapseOne. The app is redirecting me to this url on card link click

Answer (score 0):

Please
Edit the href
From
href="#collapseOne"

To
href="collapseOne"

Collapsible Group Item #1

Comment: You mean replace the same text with the same text? I don't get this

Comment: I mean replace    href="#collapseOne"

Comment: With  href="collapseOne"

Comment: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'collapseTwo'. The application starts breaking

Comment: Do same for collapseTwo and collapseThree

Comment: href="collapseOne"    and href="collapseTwo"  and href=collapseThree"